# Execute two queries at the same time on psql with node postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have two independent queries for example:

```
const query = "SELECT PG_SLEEP(30);"
const query1 = "SELECT PG_SLEEP(30);"

console.time("Query")
await Promise.all([pgClient.query(query), pgClient.query(query1)]);
console.timeEnd("Query")
```

This, according to the documentation, will be added to a queue and execute one after the other, is it possible to execute the two queries asynchronously? so the registered time should be around 30 instead of 60...

UPDATE:
Other approach would be to use [the pool feature](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool) of the library instead of instantiating two clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you have to open two database connections. Then it is no problem to have two queries running concurrently.

Comment: Yeap that works too, I thought there's a way w/o using that approach

Comment: No, that is the only way.